# Chrome Extension - Listen to button click events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Consider that I am a beginner and this is my first code in relation to this.

I made a Chrome extension to listen for click events on a certain button...

Follow code:

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("#statusContainter > div:nth-child(5) a").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            var nomeClient = document.querySelector("#contact-info > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) a").innerText
            var primeiroNome = nomeClient.split(' ')
            var numeroChamado = document.querySelector("#dvSubHeader > div.dt-sub-cont > div:nth-child(3) > div.pl63.mw75per > div > div.mr15 a").innerText
            document.querySelector("#ticketReplyContainer div").click()
            var stamp = new Date();
            var hours = stamp.getHours();
    
            if (hours >= 18 && hours < 24) {
                time = "boa noite"
            } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
                time = "boa tarde"
            } else if (hours >= 0 && hours < 12) {
                time = "bom dia"
            }
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                texto = `${primeiroNome[0] == '.' || primeiroNome[0] == ',' ? primeiroNome[1] : primeiroNome[0]}, ${time}. \n\n` +
                    `Esta é a confirmação de que seu chamado de Nº ${numeroChamado}, foi finalizado pelo setor do suporte e seu caso foi dado como solucionado.\n\n` +
    
                    'Favor não responder a este e-mail.\n\n' +
    
                    `Caso tenha qualquer outra dificuldade na plataforma, basta abrir um novo chamado através do link:\n\n` +
    
                    `https://support.zoho.com/portal/waveatendimento/pt/newticket\n\n` +
    
                    'Att,\n' +
                    'Suporte Wave'
                console.log(primeiroNome[0] == '.' || primeiroNome[0] == ',' ? primeiroNome[1] : primeiroNome[0])
                document.querySelector("#replyContainer div > iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(1)").innerText = texto
                //document.querySelector("#send_option_container > div.dis_tab div").click()
            }, 1500)
        })
    }, 2000)
```

As ugly as the code is, it works for what I need!

What happens is... It only works on the first click of the button.

The other click's the system does not hear.

How can I fix this?

It is also interesting to say that:

I have the following website: https://desk.zoho.com/support/waveatendimento/ShowHomePage.do#Cases

Inside that URL I have tickets, and inside each ticket this button I want to hear the click event.

Every ticket I click on, just changes the end of the URL... Could this be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you using two nested `setTimeouts`?

Comment: It was the way I knew how to do what I need.

Because I need to wait for the DOM of the page to load and then run my script.

Tried to use AddEventListener but had problems.

Comment: Regarding the click of the button, the script runs only once... Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: The problem is what I've mentioned above, remove the inner one and it should work

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this? A code as an example?

Comment: Your addEventListener should work normally if it's pointing to the proper DOM element. Try placing a `console.log("click")` at the beginning of its callback to check how it logs